# How to write to and read data from Android's ApplicationContext?

Tags: android

In my app I need a central storage object that will be accessed from different parts of the application (like a singleton data holder).

AFAIK the clean way to implement singletons in Android is to use the `ApplicationContext`.

How can I

1. put data (like instance of `List<MyPieceOfInformation>`) in the `ApplicationContext` and
2. get them out of it

?

Is it correct that the only way to store more or less complex data in Android is to use the built-in SQLite database?

Comment: you can always create a class based on android's Application class. just extend it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: @DavidM Isn't that considered a bad style?

Comment: I hope not...it (Application class) for just such a scenario. typically you won't need it, but it is convenient to store info that's needed throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql and others as well.
it is all depends if you want to save the data in local or external.
as external, for example, you can use mysql and web server, then communicate using json.

for saving List, you can use static.

Answer (score 0):

> In my app I need a central storage object that will be accessed from different parts of the application (like a singleton data holder).

Then use a singleton.

> AFAIK the clean way to implement singletons in Android is to use the ApplicationContext.

First, there is nothing in Android named `ApplicationContext`. You probably mean `Application`.

Second, in the opinion of many experts (myself included), a custom `Application` is less "clean" than regular singletons.

> Is it correct that the only way to store more or less complex data in Android is to use the built-in SQLite database?

Comparing a singleton to a database is like comparing an apple and an asteroid, on the grounds that both are made of matter and, in English, begin with the letter "a".

A database is persistent. You use a database when you want to save data persistently.

A singleton is not persistent. You use a singleton for transient data, such as a cache of data that is backed by a database.